# How to fill to lower-right corner in python-curses

Tags: python-3.x, python-curses

I'm using curses in Python3.3 and need to fill the entire usable space with characters.  The error I'm getting occurs when my double for loop reaches the last corner.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
    curses.wrapper(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/curses/__init__.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwds)
  File "main.py", line 9, in main
    stdscr.addch(y, x, ord('.'))
_curses.error: addch() returned ERR
```

I've noticed that each time a character is added, the cursor moves to the right.  I haven't tested this as thoroughly as I might have, but I suspect that the cursor leaves the end of the window on that last call to stdscr.addch, which likely causes the error.

An additional note is that by using a maximum width or height one unit under what the window returns, I'm able to loop without an error.

Source that fails:

```
import curses

def main(stdscr):
    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            stdscr.addch(y, x, ord('.'))
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

For my project, it's important that I use a complete rectangle.  Up to this point I've shortened my max width from 80 to 79, but if anyone knows a way to write to that last corner, I'd like to hear it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling **insch** in corner instead of **addch** worked for me.

Comment: A little late on accepting your answer, but this is still relevant to me.